# Keeping tagged word within FreqDist in Python with NLTK package

Tags: python, nltk, frequency, frequency-analysis, word-frequency

I would like to differentiate words that spell the SAME way but have different genres in my FreqDist count.

For instance in the sentence:

> *The **dog** seemed to **dog** the turtle*.

I would like to have one count for the 'dog' as a **noun**, one for the 'dog' as a **verb**, and not two for the word 'dog'.

I thank you for your wise suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look into [NLTK - Chapter 5](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) and think about creating part of speech pairs, and then using conditional frequency distributions